# Why would LVSCW_AUTOSIZE_USEHEADER stretch my first column to match width of listview control's width?

Tags: c++, listview, winapi

I'm working with Comctl32.dll's list-view control and attempting to divide the width of it amongst 10 columns, auto-sizing to match the strings in their respective headers. I am using the ListView_SetColumnWidth macro with the LVSCW_AUTOSIZE_USEHEADER value, and it's working with every column except the first one:
[image]

[image]

Here's the code I think is relevant, but please let me know if it's not enough:

```
HWND hListView;
        hListView = CreateWindowEx(
            WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
            WC_LISTVIEW,
            L"",
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE |
            LVS_REPORT,
            200, 10, 800, 150,
            hwnd,
            (HMENU)IDC_MAIN_LV,
            GetModuleHandle(NULL),
            NULL);
        if (hListView == NULL) {
            MessageBox(hwnd, L"Could not create list box.", L"Error!", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        }

        LVCOLUMN lvc; 
        WCHAR buffer[256];
        lvc.mask = LVCF_FMT | LVCF_WIDTH | LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_SUBITEM;

        for (int col = 0; col < C_COLUMNS; col++) {     

            lvc.iSubItem = col;
            lvc.pszText = buffer;
            lvc.cx = 100;
            lvc.fmt = LVCFMT_CENTER;

            LoadString(
                GetModuleHandle(NULL),
                IDS_HP + col,
                buffer,
                sizeof(buffer));

            if (ListView_InsertColumn(hListView, col, &lvc) == -1) {
                MessageBox(hwnd, L"Could not create list box.", L"Error!", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
            }
            ListView_SetColumnWidth(hListView, col, LVSCW_AUTOSIZE_USEHEADER);
        }

        SetFocus(hListBox);
```

This is my first project after learning the basics of C++ so I'm sure I'm doing everything shown here the worst way possible. (: **Specifically**, I'd like to know what's causing this particular error please. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [ListView_SetColumnWidth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-listview_setcolumnwidth) documentation:

> **LVSCW_AUTOSIZE_USEHEADER**
>
> Automatically sizes the column to fit the header text. If you use this value with the last column, its width is set to fill the remaining width of the list-view control.

When you use this for the first time, there's only one column, so it **is** the last column and therefore gets resized to the full width of the listview.

The solution is to add all your columns first and then autosize them.

```
for (int col = 0; col < C_COLUMNS; col++) {     
    lvc.iSubItem = col;
    lvc.pszText = buffer;
    lvc.cx = 100;
    lvc.fmt = LVCFMT_CENTER;

    LoadString(
        GetModuleHandle(NULL),
        IDS_HP + col,
        buffer,
        sizeof(buffer));

    ListView_InsertColumn(hListView, col, &lvc);
}
for (int col = 0; col < C_COLUMNS; col++) {     
   ListView_SetColumnWidth(hListView, col, LVSCW_AUTOSIZE_USEHEADER);
}
```